# coredata - fetch one attribute into an array

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

**Aim:** I would like to fetch the value of one attribute (from an entity) from the database (core data) into an array.

**Example**

Entity Name = Employees

Attribute   = employeeID

I just want all the employeeIDs populated into an array / set.

**Question**

Given below is my implementation, I just feel it is kind of a round about way, I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

**Code**

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Employees"];

fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"employeeID", nil]];

NSError *error      = nil;
NSArray *results    = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                               error:&error];

NSMutableArray *employeeIDs = [NSMutableArray array];

for(id currentRecord in results)
{
    [employeeIDs addObject:[currentRecord objectForKey:@"employeeID"]];
}
```

Comment: Use the fetch as dictionaries fetch request option, and specify "employeeID" as your key to fetch. Check NSFetchRequest.h.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can avoid the last for loop,

Instead of,

```
NSMutableArray *employeeIDs = [NSMutableArray array];

for(id currentRecord in results)
{
    [employeeIDs addObject:[currentRecord objectForKey:@"employeeID"]];
}
```

Try this,

```
NSMutableArray *employeeIDs = [results valueForKey:@"employeeID"];
```

Comment: Just a heads up to anyone else: valueForKey returns an NSArray. If you really need it to be mutable, call mutableCopy on the results. 
NSMutableArray *employeeIDs = [[results valueForKey:@"employeeID"] mutableCopy];

Answer (score 18):

One way of doing it is-

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Employees"];
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

NSError *error      = nil;
NSArray *results    = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                               error:&error];

NSMutableArray *employeeIDs = [results valueForKey:@"employeeID"];
```

Comment: You can limit the attributes returned to what you need by using 
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"<#Attribute name#>"]]; See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html